# StreamReader and Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, filestream, streamreader, streamwriter, portable-class-library

I am writing a ConfigManager class using Portable Class Libraries. PCL supports `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` classes that I want to use, but the PCL version of those classes do not support passing in a string during construction.  PCL also does not support the `reader.Close()` and `writer.Close()`. Lastly it doesn't support the `FileStream` class.

So I am looking for an answer to any one of the following questions:

1. How can I get the `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` classes working
   in a PCL?
2. How can I create a new `stream` using PCL?
3. What other alternitives do I have to load and save files in a PCL?

Comment: Does it support disposing the stream objects? Because that should close it just fine.

Comment: Instead of .Close() use .Dispose(),
no there is no solution,
 because there isn't a problem...file system access must be abstracted
Just code against interfaces.

Check:
[link]hthttps://pclstorage.codeplex.com

[link](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/tree/v3/Plugins/Cirrious/File)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Dispose()` instead of `Close()` (or just wrap everything in a using statement).  We've hidden/removed `Close()` in Windows Store apps and newer PCLs, because it does the same thing and people would be confused about which one to call.

Consider using [PCL Storage](https://github.com/dsplaisted/pclstorage) for cross platform file system access.

Here are some blog posts you may want to refer to for how to approach platform-specific functionality in PCLs:

- [How to Make Portable Class Libraries Work for You](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2012/08/27/how-to-make-portable-class-libraries-work-for-you.aspx)
- [Portable Class Library Enlightenment / Adaptation](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/11/portable-class-library-enlightenment.html)
- [Using Target-Specific Code in a Portable Library](http://www.cognitiveinheritance.com/post/Using-Target-Specific-Code-in-a-Portable-Library.aspx)

Comment: PCLStorage is async which is often inconvinient. Especially it is sad to use async PCLStorage on .NET/Xamarin/WP8 where System.IO exists on all platforms.

Comment: To whoever reading this answer that would use PCL storage.
PCL Storage isn't maintained anymore, I would advice not using it on a production application.
Prefer implementing your own storage solution using dependency injection

Answer (score 2):

found the answer over here (by Rob Caplan): http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/386eb3b2-e98e-4bbc-985f-fc143db6ee36/read-local-file-in-portable-library#386eb3b2-e98e-4bbc-985f-fc143db6ee36

> File access cannot be done portably between Windows Store apps and
>   Windows Phone 8 apps. You will have to use platform specific code, to
>   open the file and acquire a stream. You can then pass the stream into
>   the PCL.
>
> Since both Windows Store apps and Windows Phone 8 apps use the
>   essentially the same Windows (Phone) Runtime classes from 
>   Windows.Storage to open files you can share the code (but not the
>   binary) by linking a code file between the two projects. See Share
>   code with Add as Link .
>
> See Maximize code reuse between Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8 for more
>   techniques for sharing code.

If anyone has a solution other than this I would be interested to hear it; also wondering about the `.Close()` methods in the PCL.